# pandas select rows in a multi-level index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know why the functionality exists to access the rows of a multilevel indexed series by key, but it does not exist for dataframes.

For example, I have the following dataframe:

```
    index_1 index_2 num_1   num_2
0   a       c       1       2
1   a       c       4       3
2   a       c       3       4
3   a       d       2       3
4   b       d       3       1
5   b       d       2       3
```

I now perform a groupby operation as follows:

```
group_single_col = test.groupby(['index_1', 'index_2'])['num_1'].max()
```

I have no problems doing:

```
group_single_col[('a')]
```

or

```
group_single_col[('a', 'c')]
```

which is an amazing functionality, allowing me to slice based on values of the different index levels.

However, if I do a groupby and extract more than one column, as follows:

```
group_double_col = test.groupby(['index_1', 'index_2'])[['num_1', 'num_2]].max()
```

the object that is returned is a DataFrame and although the multilevel index is realized, operations like:

```
group_double_col[('a')]
```

fail.

I understand that in the first case a series is returned, and in the second case a dataframe is returned, but I still thought that the functionality should work fine with a dataframe.

The follow up question is, what workaround is there in the case of a dataframe?

Currently I do:

```
grouped[(grouped.index.get_level_values('index_1')=='a')]
```

but I question if there is a more efficient method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (group_double_col.xs('a', axis=0, level=0))
         num_1  num_2
index_2              
c            4      4
d            2      3

print (group_double_col.xs('a', axis=0, level=0, drop_level=False))
                 num_1  num_2
index_1 index_2              
a       c            4      4
        d            2      3
```

Comment: I just realized you can also do something like `group_double_col.reset_index()` and then slice like a regular dataframe.

Comment: Yes, it is another solution. It depends what you need. Because if selecting by `index` is very fast.